# CORS error on request to public resource from a intranet web page

Tags: google-chrome, cors, microsoft-edge, private-network-access

I have a local web server set up at `192.168.1.39` with domain `www.server.local`. DNS has been configured to resolve this properly on my router.

Everything worked just fine until recently. My browser started to report the following error if I access page like `www.server.local/page.html` that references external resources.

```
Access to CSS stylesheet at 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reveal.js@4.1.0/dist/reset.css' from origin 'http://www.server.local' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

However, if `http://192.168.1.39/page.html` is used, the page opens properly.

But the error message really confuses me, because it suggests the css hosted at jsdelivr is in a private address space! Seriously?! Or did I miss something?

My Browser: Microsoft Edge 94.0.992.31 (Official build) (x86_64)

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

1. Open Edge and navigate to `edge://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests`
2. Disable the highlighted option `Block insecure private network requests`.
3. Restart Edge and test again.

For more details, you could refer to this blog: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-update/

Comment: This is more like a hack and works in a single browser. However, I'm serving pages in LAN to other clients as well, and asking everyone to configure their browsers is quite cumbersome. Is it possible to fix this globally? (Or is this a confirmed bug of Chromium that it's well grounded to ask them to upgrade their browser?)